# Error installing tables via pip

Tags: python, pandas, pip, pytables

I'm tying to install tables as follows (I have no sudo permissions):

```
pip install --user tables
```

And I get the following error:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-pWg1M_/tables/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-mOibUT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-pWg1M_/tables Storing debug log for failure in /home/hudson/pg/fkgm22/.pip/pip.log
```

I can install other packages with this method, but not tables... any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can check the log pip has mentioned at /home/hudson/pg/fkgm22/.pip/pip.log to see what went wrong. I guess you will get a much more detailed error message which you can try to analyse.

Comment: This is the error: InstallationError: Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-1euVua/tables/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-7AQAHv-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --user failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1euVua/tables